# what is the diffenence beteen -8 >> 12 and (-8 >> 12) in python?

Tags: python-3.x, math, computer-science

I would like to know to combine - and << or >> used in number, but i find some situation can't explain by myself. like:

```
In [44]: -12 << 1
Out[44]: -24

In [45]: -(12 << 1)
Out[45]: -24

In [46]: -(8 << 12)
Out[46]: -32768

In [47]: -8 << 12
Out[47]: -32768

In [48]: -(8 >> 12)
Out[48]: 0

In [49]: -8 >> 12
Out[49]: -1
```

the operation of -8 >> 12 is -1, can anython tell me the reason

Comment: 8 >> 22 is equal to 0 so -0 is also zero

Comment: @firefantasy, Try `-8 >> 1`, `-8 >> 2`, `-8 >> 3`, `-8 >> 4`, `-8 >> 5`.  What results do you see?